# Как добавить поиск слова из текста для отображения ответа в Telegram боте на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем доброго времени суток. В Python практически не разбираюсь, но хочу.
В общем, такой вопрос.

Есть документ с текстом. В нем записаны определенные слова (допустим, "Елка, снеговик, дедушка, снегурочка", а также варианты опечаток на эти слова (пример, "Едка, Клка, Елаа" и т.п.). В зависимости от набранного слова, есть варианты ответа (если пользователь пишет, допустим, "Елка", бот должен ответить(наверное ответ лучше в виде инлайн кнопок будет): "Возможно вы хотите узнать следующее: 1. Стоимость елки, 2. Размеры, 3. Доставка."
Название вариантов(1, 2 и 3) сейчас не суть важно, при выборе одного из них, нужно просто отобразить заранее заготовленный текст.
Проблема в количестве слов, которые надо проверить. По сути, всего слова можно разделить на 5-8 групп(можно даже сказать, на 5-8 условий). Т.е. если пользователь написал слово из одной группы, то выводится нужный ответ(при чем, для слов этой группы ответ всегда один, не меняется).

Если есть по этому вопросу какая-то документация не на английском(будучи начинающим, очень сложно понимать объяснения на англе), или соображения как это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

P.S., нашел код тут на сайте, но, как и писал выше, не пойму как в подобный код впихнуть большой объем слов на проверку. Может создать 8 отдельных файлов(каждый со своим набором слов, которые в других файлах не повторяются) и сделать 8 условий (if) на соответствие слов из этих файлов? Опять же, не пойму как подобное сделать.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):

# Если пользователь отправил "привет, как тебя зовут?" отвечаем "робот я"
if message.text == "привет, как тебя зовут?":
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'робот я'

# Если пользователь отправил "и чо?" отвечаем "да ничо"
elif message.text == "и чо?":
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'да ничо'

#Если пользователь отправил слово/фразу, на которое(ую) нет ответа
else:
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Извините, я Вас не понимаю")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего в голову не пришло, помимо этого:

```
    if message.text in ['Елка','елка','едка','йолка']:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'''
        Что именно вас интересует о Ёлках?..и т.д.
        ''')
```

Comment: Ну тогда хоть `message.text.lower()` и можно убрать `Елка` и всё с высоким регистром

Comment: Акцент был на решение, а это очевидно, так что думаю проблем бы с этим не было)

Comment: а если у меня скажем слов 100-200(склонения и однокоренные слова и варианты их опечаток тоже) в условии(которое триггерит сообщение "Что именно вас интересует о Елках"), эффективно их будет помещать так все? в принципе можно и так, но простите за возможно глупый вопрос, можно ли в таком случае все эти слова(100-200 вариантов слов на тему елку для триггера вопроса) вставить в кавычки разом?

Comment: Сам точно не скажу что эффективно, так как сам относительно немного знаю, но да, так можно, но оно будет занимать очень много места в коде.
Что бы не занимать много места, можно сделать отдельный файл, в котором будут эти елки, допустим файл елки.txt и с ним сравнивать

Answer (score 0):

[@Magius](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478462/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-telegram-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyt/1570629#comment2648367_1478622)

> а если у меня скажем слов 100-200(склонения и однокоренные слова и варианты их опечаток тоже) в условии(которое триггерит сообщение "Что именно вас интересует о Елках"), эффективно их будет помещать так все? в принципе можно и так, но простите за возможно глупый вопрос, можно ли в таком случае все эти слова(100-200 вариантов слов на тему елку для триггера вопроса) вставить в кавычки разом? –
> Magius

Что бы не прописывать в основном коде, напиши эти слова в другом коде, и импортируй его в основной.